# In pywinauto, how can I right click my app icon in the system tray to open the context menu?

Tags: python, windows, automation, pywinauto, qsystemtrayicon

How can i right click the app's icon in the systemtray and select one of the popup menuitem using pywinauto?

I have my app on the Windows Desktop systemtray,which can't be loaded using the .exe file. So i have to right click on the systemtray icon and select one of the popup menu item in order to get the app's GUI.I was trying to achieve this using pywinauto using python 64 bit.

Here is my code.

```
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="explorer")
sys_tray = app.window(class_name="Shell_TrayWnd")
loc = sys_tray.child_window(title='App name').click()
```

This is changing the mouse position to the required App's icon,but its not right clicking on that and i want to select one menu item from that pop up also.
how can i get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is method `.click_input(button="right")` which moves real cursor and performs real click. In your case it would look so (on Windows 10 version 1803):

```
#from __future__ import print_function
from pywinauto import Desktop

d = Desktop(backend='uia')
#d.Taskbar.dump_tree()
main_tray_toolbar = d.Taskbar.child_window(title="User Promoted Notification Area", control_type="ToolBar")
#print(main_tray_toolbar.texts())

icon = main_tray_toolbar.child_window(title_re="Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client.*", control_type="Button")
icon.click_input(button="right")

#d.ContextMenu.dump_tree()
d.ContextMenu.wait('visible', timeout=10) # flexibly wait up to 10 sec.
d.ContextMenu.child_window(title="About", control_type="MenuItem").invoke()
```

Helpful debug prints are commented (all `.child_window` specifications have been just copied from `dump_tree()` output). There is also method `d.windows()` that is available for master branch only (pywinauto 0.6.6 is coming in nearest 2 weeks).

Comment: Hi,Vasily..It worked fine for me in one system.. on the other system i am getting the error as below:
  File "C:\Users\isreedex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 246, in __resolve_control
    criteria)
  File "C:\Users\isreedex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 453, in wait_until_passes
    raise errpywinauto.timings.TimeoutError
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError:

Comment: Which line exactly fails? If waiting for context menu failed, you have to use `d.ContextMenu.wait('visible', timeout=10)` (or more than 10 sec.) because default timeout is 5 sec.

Comment: If this is for `icon`, the problem might be a different title on the second system.

Comment: By the way, this code shouldn't work on Win8.1 or earlier. Some early Win10 versions have another toolbar structure. In this case it's possible to use old experimental module `pywinauto.taskbar` (need `from pywinauto import taskbar`). This module uses "win32" backend. Sample code can be found in unit tests: [pywinauto/unittests/test_taskbar.py#L158](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/pywinauto/unittests/test_taskbar.py#L158)

Comment: ok. if am going witrh Desktop module, if the app's GUI is launched, how can i access the elements in the GUI? you have any document for this type of cases?

Comment: It works the same way as for `Application` object but there is no binding to particular process. See [Getting Started Guide -> Entry Points for Automation](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#entry-points-for-automation). There are some [HowTo's](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowTo.html) as well.

Comment: Method `.windows()` to list top level wrappers has been just implemented in `Desktop` class so pywinauto==0.6.5 doesn't have it, 0.6.6 is coming next week.

Comment: Hi Vasily. Sorry for late reply. I could done that. But now i want to write a common function which will take the group element as an argument. When i write that, i am getting the error: raise MatchError(items = name_control_map.keys(), tofind = search_text)
pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'dumpoption' in 'dict_keys(['Reapply', 'ReapplyCheckBox', 'CheckBox]               My code is : def capturedump_selection(dumpoption):
 print(dumpoption)
 dlg.dumpoption.select()   . But when i call that function with the inspect name as an argument, it shows error. Why this happening?

Comment: It's incorrect usage. Should be `dlg[dumoption].select()` or `getattr(dlg, dumpoption).select()`. Current code is equivalent to `dlg["dumpoption"].select()` which doesn't use variable value, but just its name.

Comment: Can you give a proper document of this library?

Comment: Core concept is described here: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Comment: Function `getattr` is a built-in Python function.

Comment: is it possible to read a value from text edit field using pywinauto? i tried this but it returning empty lists. my code is     
        dlg.child_window(title="Launch HCI Commander...", auto_id="BTHCICommandBtn", control_type="Button").click_input()
        hci= self.dlg.child_window(title="HCI Commander", auto_id="BTHCIcommand", control_type="Window")
        hci.child_window(auto_id="HcitextBox1", control_type="Edit").type_keys('05fc')
        hci.Send.click_input() 
        txt = hci.child_window(auto_id="ResponsetextBox2", control_type="Edit").texts()
        print(txt)

Comment: There is no static value provided for that field

Comment: Maybe `.get_value()` would help if it exists for this control. Or `.iface_value.GetValue()` otherwise.

Comment: If you could provide `Inspect.exe` screenshot for target field, it would be very helpful. Anyway this is another question. I would suggest to accept this answer if it resolves initial problem (gray check box under voting buttons should work for you) and ask another question with tag "pywinauto" and all the details.

Comment: Accepting correct answers is considered polite on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Comment on Vasily's answer: because the names of the windows and toolbars are localized, the code will not work on systems whose locale is not English. I got this to work on a French Windows 10 system by replacing

```
main_tray_toolbar = d.Taskbar.child_window(title="User Promoted Notification Area", control_type="ToolBar")
```

with

```
main_tray_toolbar = d.window(class_name='Shell_TrayWnd').child_window(class_name='ToolbarWindow32', control_type="ToolBar")
```